# Creating a simple portable bitmask and using it

Tags: c++, c

This is my first time trying to create a bitmask, and although seemingly simple I have having trouble visualizing everything.

Keep in mind I cannot use `std::bitset`

First, I have read that accessing raw bits is undefined behavior. (so using a union of a char would be bad because the bits might be reversed for a different compiler).

Most code I've looked at uses a struct to define each bit, and this way of structuring data should be compiler independent because the first bit will always be the LSB.  (I assume)  Here is an example:

```
struct foo
{
    unsigned char a : 1;
    unsigned char b : 1;
    unsigned char unused : 6;
};
```

Now the question is...could you use more than one bit for a variable in the struct AND have it still be comipiler independent? It seems like the answer is yes, but I have had some weird answers and want to be sure.  Something like:

```
struct foo
{
    unsigned char ab : 2;
    unsigned char unused : 6;
};
```

It seems like regardless if the raw structure is reversed, the first bit accessed from the struct is always the LSB, so how many bits you use should not matter.

Comment: That is not guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not specify the ordering of fields within a unit -- there's no guarantee that `a`, in your example, is in the LSB. If you want fully portable behavior, you need to do the bit manipulation yourself, using unsigned integral types, and (if using unsigned integral types bigger than a byte) you need to worry about the endianness when reading/writing them from external sources.

Comment: So basically the compiler could pack the value '2' of an unsigned char as 0000 0010  OR as 0100 0000.   Thus to actually use a mask I would need to set the mask after compile time? Basically no magic numbers to mask.

Comment: I would avoid bitfields for data you intend to read/write to bytestreams. And if you're worried about inner loop performance, on non-Clang compilers I would avoid them altogether. Bit manipulation on unsigned integral types, in contrast, is as dependably cross-platform as they come.

Comment: I think there might be something I'm not understanding.  How would an unsigned integral type be dependable on compilers that pack bits differently.  I've been told by multiple ppl that they have been burned when masking because of how different compilers pack bits.

Comment: There's no "packing of bits" in an integer. The LSB is the LSB. It's 1. Byte ordering is another issue, but one that's easily handled, and only relevant when moving data between architectures.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour does not depend on the bit order. What you have written corresponds to the language standard and therefore behaves the same on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Bitfields cannot be portably used to access specific bits in an external block of data (like a hardware register or data serialized in a stream of bytes). So bitfields aren't useful in this context - at least for portable code.

But if you're talking about using the bitfield within the program and not trying to have it model some external bit representation, then it's 100% portable.  Not super useful, but portable.

Comment: I need to set some values very quickly and would otherwise need some type of comparison statement to do so.  The mask should allow for me to set certain values and leave certain values without needing to check states, thus being faster in general.  Is this not true?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be any faster. I suspect not, but I'd need to see code to be sure. Bitfields incur a cost to access them; have a read of: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/11/26/9143050.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a career twiddling bits in C/C++, and maybe because of this issue, I never see it done this way. We always use unsigned variables and apply bit masks to them:

```
#define BITMASK_A  0x01
#define BITMASK_B  0x02

unsigned char bitfield;
```

Then when you want to access a, you use `(bitfield & BITMASK_A)`

But to answer your question, there should be no logical difference between your two examples, if the compiler places ab at the low end, then the first example should also place a at the LSb.

Comment: I thought that pre-defining the mask is what would mess up if packing was different between compilers. So if you develop on compiler A and it packs '5' as 0000 0101 but you test on compiler B and it packs it as 1010 0000 then the mask could be incorrect.

Comment: That's where `htonl()` and `ntohl()` come in.

Comment: I am not allowed library functions.  I could write them, but wouldn't calling a function to rearrange the bit order kind of defeat the purpose of bitmasking.  I mean, what is the cost of a function call compared to a comparison statement, probably fairly close.

Comment: Both of you might be confusing packing with byte order (little-endian, big endian).  Packing means that fields in a struct might get padding to meet alignment preferences.  Every compiler has a 'packed' directive you can use to eliminate padding. 

A bitmask is consistent with the endianness of the variable (at least to unsigned long) and is portable.